# How to make code that runs a process once per file parallel?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import cv2
import time
import glob

img_array = []
start_time = time.time()
for files in glob.glob("C:/pictures/*.jpg"):
    a = cv2.imread(files)
    img_array.append(a)
    height, width,layer = a.shape
    size = (width, height)
video = cv2.VideoWriter('C:/pictures/project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 15, size)

for value in range(len(img_array)):
    video.write(img_array[value])
video.release()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This is the serial code I made first. The program is merging several images and making video using cv2 library.

```
import cv2         
import time
import glob
from multiprocessing import Process
img_array = []
def convert():
    start_time = time.time()
    for files in glob.glob("C:/pictures/*.jpg"):
        a = cv2.imread(files)
        img_array.append(a)
        height, width,layer = a.shape
        size = (width, height)
        video = cv2.VideoWriter('C:/pictures/project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 15, size)
    for value in range(len(img_array)):
        video.write(img_array[value])
    video.release()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs =[]
    proc = Process(target = convert, args='')   
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

And this is the parallel version of the upper serial code.
I used multiprocessing-Process. But parallel should be faster than serial but my code, parallel version is usually slower or similar to serial. I am even not sure my parallel code is the correct way to convert my serial code to parallel.
If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

```
import cv2
import time    
import glob
import multiprocessing

shape = 1000,1000
img_array = []

def convert(files):
    a = cv2.imread(files)
    resized = cv2.resize(a,shape)
    img_array.append(resized)
    video = cv2.VideoWriter('C:/pictures/project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 15, shape)

    for i in range(len(img_array)):
        video.write(img_array[i]) 
    video.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for files in glob.glob("C:/pictures/*.jpg"):
        p.apply_async(convert, [files])
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This is code for the comment below.

Comment: You want to do the glob _before_ you start the subprocesses, so you can start one subprocess per file the glob expression evaluates to. Right now you're only starting one process total so there's no parallelization added at all.

Comment: BTW, just to be sure, did you check your CPU utilization and make sure that there are unused cores? If you're calling functions that are parallel themselves, your program may already use all available CPU resources, in which case creating subprocesses would just cause contention and thus slow it down further. (I don't know cv2, but numpy is an example of a Python library that parallelizes many operations automatically, and thus where attempts to use multiprocessing backfire)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your reply and for checking problem points. I am new to parallel programming and I thought parallel is applied since I added 'Process'(multiprocessing) before going to the 'convert' function wherever glob is located. I have been trying to apply your comments and you mean the glob location should be changed? Could you briefly explain how can I make it parallel? Thank you so much

Comment: The answer Adam added shows the appropriate pattern -- creating `Process` instances in a loop over the glob results. If you only create one `Process`, `multiprocessing` gives you no benefit over just running your logic in the main/original process; it needs to be multiple processes created for `multiprocessing` to do anything useful.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thank you for your comment. I tried it but when doing 'for files in glob.glob()' part in my coding, it says 'convert() takes 1 positional argument but 44 were given'. I think it happens because many files are in for loop. Is there any recommended ways to solve this problem? I can upload code with it if needed.

Comment: Please do show code that demonstrates the error -- it sounds like you created just one process with 44 arguments instead of 44 processes with one argument each; what you need to do is the latter.

Comment: ...thinking about it, I suspect the part of Adam's answer you missed is the use of `[f]` instead of `f` -- it's important to put the result in a list or a one-item tuple (which would be `(f,)`), because the thing passed as `args` gets treated as a sequence and unpacked, so if you put `'hello.txt'` directly in there as the argument list, it makes `'h'` one argument, `e` the second one, `l` the third, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for detailed suggestion. I used [] and now It's worked. I'm not sure why the error happened even I used []. I attached the code to the question and another problem happens that the video only has some images, not all (same extensions and size). Could you tell suggestion for solving this if you know? Thank you

Comment: The most visible problem in the code just edited in is having lots of processes all trying to write to the same output file at the same time; that isn't expected to work in general. (BTW, it's generally appropriate to mark your existing question as answered and ask a new/different one once the initial problem has been solved and you're on to a different issue, even if it's with the same code).

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of my multiprocessing code. The following code processes multiple files at once within a specified folder. Simply, create a folder where you'd like to dump all your files for parallel processing. I named my folder, "Folder." It is also important to create another folder for where your test file will live for initializing the function. This file can be an excel test dummy. For this example, I created a folder titled, "mastertemp" and added a test file titled, "mastertemp.xlsx"

Also, with the code I provided, the multiprocessing speed is dependent on the number of CPUs available. I generally use Google Cloud - AI Notebooks. I'm able to set a specified number of CPUs. For instance, if I have 8 CPUs, the code will process 8 files simultaneously until there are no more files to process.

I hope this helps out!

```
import multiprocessing
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import os
import time

# MULTI-PROCESS

# created a 'mastertemp' folder and inserted a test excel file to launch the parallel process

file = 'mastertemp/mastertemp.xlsx'   # add a test file and set file equal to "mastertemp.xlsx"; initializing
def process(file):
    '''
    write your code here; what do you want to do with the files? Below, I simply am reading to df

    '''
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    print(file)

p = multiprocessing.Pool()

# created a 'Folder' titled folder where all excel files will live
# f = excel files
for f in glob.glob("Folder/*.xlsx"):
    # launch a process for each file (ish).
    # The result will be approximately one process per CPU core available.
    p.apply_async(process, [f])
p.close()
p.join() # Wait for all child processes to close.
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I tried it but I got the problem. When doing 'for files in glob.glob() part in my coding, it says 'convert() takes 1 positional argument but 44 were given'.
I think it happens because many files are in for loop. Is there any recommendations to solve this problem?  I can upload code with it if needed.

Comment: @BellaLee, ...the goal is to have the loop process only one file at a time -- in the exact code in Adam's answer, `f` will only have a single filename at a given time even if there are many matches. Also, note the use of `[f]` instead of just `f` as args -- otherwise you can get each _letter_ in the string being passed as a separate argument. If your first filename has 44 characters (counting `C:/pictures`), maybe that's what went wrong.